# Wordpress AJAX request being redirected from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: ajax, wordpress, http, https

I have a simple AJAX request that is being redirected to HTTP. I have tried adding the trailing '/' and making the URL "https" as I have seen suggested on similar posts, but it is still being rejected.

```
jQuery.ajax({ url: "https://"+ host +"/wp-content/plugins/calendarview/views/updateRollOut.php/",
         data: {id: eventID, start: start},
         type: 'GET',
         success: function(output) {
                      document.getElementById(rollOutDetails).innerHTML = output;
                  }
    });
```

In google chrome console the error appears as:

```
jquery.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 
'https://pedalracing.org/newcalendar/' was loaded 
over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
'http://pedalracing.org/wp-content/plugins/calendarview/views/updateRollOut.php?
id=300770&start=1525905000'.
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

When I click to the link to the endpoint that is provided in the Chrome error, it takes me to the url:

```
https://pedalracing.org/wp-content/plugins/calendarview/views/updateRollOut.php?id=300770&start=1525905000
```

I can't figure out where/why the request is being redirected. I have looked in WordPress's 301 redirects, but there are none in there that would affect this page. Any ideas?

Comment: delete the last trailing slash from here `"https://"+ host +"/wp-content/plugins/calendarview/views/updateRollOut.php/"`. and what is your `host` variable?

Comment: The problem started when the trailing slash wasn't there, and I added it per some advice on other StackFlow questions, but it had no effect. The host variable is a string that had been working well for a few months until the site moved to https instead of http requests.

Comment: try to clear the cache of website/browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Codex article on [using Ajax in plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins). What you should do is localize your JavaScript and include a 'real' link to the resource you're wanting to go to.

Using [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) you can do the following:

```php
wp_localize_script( 'script-name', 'MY_AJAX_OBJECT',
    array( 
        'content_dir' => home_url( 'wp-content/plugins/calendarview/views/updateRollOut.php' )
    )
);
```

Place the above in your theme (*or better yet, plugin*) file (`.php`) and hook it into the same hook used to enqueue your script file. Ideally using the [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/#comment-1391) action hook.

Then you can rewrite your Ajax request to this:

```
jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url: MY_AJAX_OBJECT.content_dir,
        data: {id: eventID, start: start},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(output) {
            document.getElementById(rollOutDetails).innerHTML = output;
        }
    }
);
```